# Would a Jean Pain heater work well for heating in a USDA Zone 4A?

Tags: compost, heat

I'm considering digging a 300' (distance to the compost pile) trench 2 ways to heat constantly on a closed system as it's cheaper/easier to get a pile of wood chips than split wood. Would a wood chip [Jean Pain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Pain) heater work well for my winter heating needs, and produce requirements?

The total size of the compost pile is about 10'x100'x2', and after the first 9 months of wood chip breakdown it will provide a lot of great compost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really qualified to answer this question, but I did contact a colleague who has some experience in the area. It seems that while you can extract some heat from composting (there are various small scale efforts on Youtube, etc) it has not been adopted by commercial enterprises, perhaps because the technology exists to perform controlled burning with wood chips which is more efficient and controllable.

This link was offered which may be of assistance: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijce/2010/627930/

Comment: +1 for citing scientific paper.